# Proposition 3.5.1 in Bruns and Herzog, Cohen-Macaulay Rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, local-cohomology

Bruns and Herzog in their book Cohen-Macaulay Rings, page 128 consider a local Noetherian ring $(R,m,k)$, an $R$-module $M$ and they define the functor $\Gamma_m(\cdot)$ as $\Gamma_m(M) = \varinjlim \operatorname{Hom}_R(R/m^s,M)$. Proposition 3.5.1 says that this functor is left exact.

> ***Question***: Since $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R/m^s,\cdot)$ is a left exact functor and $\varinjlim$ is an exact functor, does it not follow immediately that $\varinjlim \operatorname{Hom}_R(R/m^s,\cdot)$ is a left exact functor? Why do we need a proof as the one given by B&H?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're right But the proof of B&H is an elementary proof that don't use exactness of $\varinjlim$ and it is kind of instructive.